# How to restart app after coming on home screen?

Tags: java, android, xml

I used this code for destroy activity using onBackPressed()..

```
   @Override

          public void onBackPressed() 
        {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
        alert.setMessage("Are you sure want to exit?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alert.setCancelable(true);
            }
        });
        alert.create().show();
}
```

I come on home screen successfully but when I open application again, app opens in resume state.So, how to restart app again?

Comment: add finish() or use intent flag CLEAR_TASK and NEW_TASK

Comment: Can you send me full code Divyesh?

Comment: odkhe 6 k nai??

Comment: odkhu j ne yaar tne to jor reputation vadhe 6 tare to mne 1 upvoting kar ne laa

Comment: use this code <br>        finishAffinity();
        startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,Home.class));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

or, other solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in SPlash screen activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
.....
```